# Color code - please explain yellow highlight

Tags: support

I notice that a green box appears around the number of answers received when an answer has been accepted. What does it mean when the whole question has a yellow background?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are those questions with your favorite tags. e.g.:

If you have `greek` and `koine-greek` as your favourite tags:

[image: tags]

The questions are displayed as follows:

[image: questions]